# React-native Xcode build archive failed

Tags: xcode, react-native, error-handling, build, ipa

I have following error during product archive in Xcode for ipa file build

Configuration :
react native version -0.59.9
Xcode version - 12.4

****tried change bundle path to everything but could not succeed
App runs fine no error on build but during product archive it fails for the above mention error****

here is the screenshot of error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HLC3.png

Answer (score 0):

try 3 steps,
1)change workspace to new build system - file/workspace settings
2)delete derived data
3)clean build folder

Comment: it shows new errors with new build system which states multiple commands produced and with legacy build system it shows (Deprecated)